# $v \in \ker(T^\ast T)$ implies $T(v)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner-product space and let $T:V \to V$ be a linear operator and $T^\ast$ the adjoint of $T$. Show $v \in \ker(T^\ast T) \Rightarrow T(v)=0$.

We are given $v \in \ker(T^\ast T) \Longleftrightarrow \langle T^\ast T(v), T^\ast T(v) \rangle = 0$

We need to show $\langle T(v), T(v) \rangle = 0 \Longleftrightarrow v \in \ker (T)$.

How do we show this?

Comment: Suppose $T^{\ast}T(v) = 0$. Then you want to see $\langle T(v), T(v)\rangle = 0$. Any idea how to relate this with $T^{\ast}T(v)$?

Answer (score 4):

If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is an inner product, then the only $x$ with $\langle x , x \rangle = 0$ is $x = 0$. This is one part of the definition of an inner product.

Using it here gives exactly what you need to complete the problem.

Comment: I have tried to use your hint, but I can't seem to use it to get me farther than $\langle T^\ast T(v), T^\ast T(v) \rangle = 0 \Rightarrow T^\ast T(v) = 0,$ but this follows directly from $v \in \ker(T^\ast T)$